# How to convert date : Sep 26 00:15:00 2020 in YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS' format in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Error while converting

```
select to_date('Sep 26 00:15:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual ;

ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0 .
```

Looking for solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `TO_DATE()`, you want to convert a string - `'Sep 26 00:15:00'` to an Oracle `DATE` type - that is a type that counts, internally, the number of seconds since an epoch date.

In Unix, that would be '1970-01-01 00:00:00', in some other databases I know '2000-01-01 00:00:00'. I don't know about Oracle.

So you convert the string: `'Sep 26 00:15:00'`. That is: the three-letter English month name abbreviation, a space, the day as two digits, a space, two digits for the 24hour-notated hour, a colon, two digits for the minutes, another colon, and two digits for the second. Nothing for the year, to be precise. The second parameter of `TO_DATE()` must describe that format. It would therefore be: `'Mon DD HH24:MI:SS'` .

The second parameter you use makes absolutely no sense in this context. You could, if you want to play, use it to re-format the converted `DATE` type, back to a string, in the ISO format, using `TO_CHAR()`:

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(
    TO_DATE('Sep 26 00:15:00','Mon DD HH24:MI:SS')
  , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
  )
FROM dual;
```

Comment: "that is a type that counts, internally, the number of seconds since an epoch date." That is incorrect; a `DATE` data type is 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second.

Comment: So Oracle is unique not only in numerics, but also in date-time types. Thanks for sharing

Comment: I get date as Sat Sep 26 00:29:00 2020 ,how can I convert this to required format

Comment: That format would be: 3-letter Eng. weekdayname, space, 3-letter Eng. monthname , space, day-day,colon,min-min,colon,sec-sec, year, so: `'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY'`. I found a good docu here: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_GCEY1DN2CN5HZCUQFHVUYQD3G.html

Answer (score 1):

How? By providing correct format masks, of course.

```
SQL> select
  2    to_char(
  3            to_date('Sep 26 00:15:00 2020', 'Mon dd hh24:mi:ss yyyy'),
  4            'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'
  5           ) result
  6  from dual;

RESULT
-------------------
2020/09/26 00:15:00

SQL>
```

Comment: I get date as Sat Sep 26 00:29:00 2020 ,how can I convert this to required format